# How do I get the golden egg from the jerk bird?

Tags: broken-age

I'm stuck as Vella in Meriloft in Broken Age. I already have the golden eggs from Jessie and the nest near M'ggie. How do I retrieve the golden egg from the nest with the jerk bird?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put the overlarge cloud shoes on the ladder.

Answer (score -1):

yea you have to get your knife from behind M'ggie using the ladder give it to C'rl to get the shoes and put them on the ladder and try it then.